# HectorSLAM implementation on Melodic

Tags: ros-melodic, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am semi-new to ROS and am  trying to run the tutorial.launch file in hectorSLAM and I’ve hit a roadblock and keep getting an error when I try to run the tutorial.launch.

I cloned HectorSLAM for melodic from https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 and ROS melodic.

The launch file is located in ~/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_slam_launch/launch and I run:

> administrator@administrator-OptiPlex-3010:~/a_ws/src/hector_slam/hector_slam_launch/launch$ roslaunch tutorial.launch

I then get the following error:

```
RLException: Invalid <arg> tag: hector_geotiff 
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/administrator/a_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
Argxml is <arg default="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps" name="geotiff_map_file_path"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have tried to launch the file multiple times and sometimes I get the error:

```
RLException: Invalid <arg> tag: hector_geotiff 
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
Argxml is <arg default="$(find hector_geotiff)/maps" name="geotiff_map_file_path"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I have set roscd as ~a_ws/devel and the HectorSLAM package has the hector_geotiff package in it

any help fixing this error would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346504/hectorslam-implementation-on-melodic/) by [Nosnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/49518/nosnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you installed `hector_geotiff` with `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-hector-geotiff`?
Do you have this folder: `/opt/ros/melodic/share/hector_geotiff` if you have already installed?
Have you tried to launch without changing `roscd` from `~` just typing `roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch`?

---

Originally posted by [tp_ink](https://answers.ros.org/users/53381/tp_ink/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1